# Tips for optimising code in Cython

Tags: python, optimization, cython

I have a relatively simple question (I think). I'm working on a piece of Cython code that computes the radius of a strain ellipse when the strain and a specific direction are given (i.e. the radius parallel to the given direction for a certain amount of strain). This function is called several milion times during each program run and profiling revealed that this function is the limiting factor performance-wise speaking. Here's the code:

```
# importing math functions from a C-library (faster than numpy)
from libc.math cimport sin, cos, acos, exp, sqrt, fabs, M_PI

cdef class funcs:

    cdef inline double get_r(self, double g, double omega):
        # amount of strain: g, angle: omega
        cdef double l1, l2, A, r, g2, gs   # defining some variables
        if g == 0: return 1   # no strain means the strain ellipse is a circle
        omega = omega*M_PI/180   # converting angle omega to radians
        g2 = g*g
        gs = g*sqrt(4 + g2)
        l1 = 0.5*(2 + g2 + gs)   # l1 and l2: eigenvalues of the Cauchy strain tensor
        l2 = 0.5*(2 + g2 - gs)
        A = acos(g/sqrt(g2 + (1 - l2)**2))   # orientation of the long axis of the ellipse
        r = 1./sqrt(sqrt(l2)*(cos(omega - A)**2) + sqrt(l1)*(sin(omega - A)**2))   # the radius parallel to omega
        return r   # return of the jedi
```

Running this code takes about 0.18 microseconds per call, which I think is a bit long for such a simple function. Also, `math.h` has a square(x) function, but I can't import it from the `libc.math` library, anyone knows how? Any other suggestions for further improving the performance of this little piece of code?

**UPDATE 2013/09/04:**

There seems to be more at play than meets the eye. When I profile one function that calls `get_r` 10 milion times I get different performance than calling another function. I've added an updated version of my partial code. When I use `get_r_profile` for profiling, I get 0.073 microsec for each call of `get_r`, whereas `MC_criterion_profile` gives me about 0.164 microsec/call of `get_r`, a 50% difference which seems to be related to the overhead cost of `return r`.

```
from libc.math cimport sin, cos, acos, exp, sqrt, fabs, M_PI

cdef class thesis_funcs:

    cdef inline double get_r(self, double g, double omega):
        cdef double l1, l2, A, r, g2, gs, cos_oa2, sin_oa2
        if g == 0: return 1
        omega = omega*SCALEDPI
        g2 = g*g
        gs = g*sqrt(4 + g2)
        l1 = 0.5*(2 + g2 + gs)
        l2 = l1 - gs
        A = acos(g/sqrt(g2 + square(1 - l2)))
        cos_oa2 = square(cos(omega - A))
        sin_oa2 = 1 - cos_oa2
        r = 1.0/sqrt(sqrt(l2)*cos_oa2 + sqrt(l1)*sin_oa2)
        return r

    @cython.profile(False)
    cdef inline double get_mu(self, double r, double mu0, double mu1):
        return mu0*exp(-mu1*(r - 1))

    def get_r_profile(self): # Profiling through this guy gives me 0.073 microsec/call
        cdef unsigned int i
        for i from 0 <= i < 10000000:
            self.get_r(3.0, 165)

    def MC_criterion(self, double g, double omega, double mu0, double mu1, double C = 0.0):
        cdef double r, mu, theta, res
        r = self.get_r(g, omega)
        mu = self.get_mu(r, mu0, mu1)
        theta = 45 - omega
        theta = theta*SCALEDPI
        res = fabs(g*sin(2.0*theta)) - mu*(1 + g*cos(2.0*theta)) - C
        return res

    def MC_criterion_profile(self): # Profiling through this one gives 0.164 microsec/call
        cdef double g, omega, mu0, mu1
        cdef unsigned int i
        omega = 165
        mu0 = 0.6
        mu1 = 2.0
        g = 3.0
        for i from 1 <= i < 10000000:
            self.MC_criterion(g, omega, mu0, mu1)
```

I think there might be a fundamental difference between `get_r_profile` and `MC_criterion` which causes extra overhead cost. Can you spot it?

Comment: Your `<math.h>` has a `square` function? That's not a standard function, which platform are you on? In any case, you can define your own `cdef inline square(x): return x * x` to get rid of all the calls to `pow`.

Comment: The function *call* might be faster if you decouple `get_r` from the class. There's no need to pass `self` if you don't need it.

Comment: @larsmans Tried both suggestions, no significant gains though. The 2nd last line `r = 1./...` is by far the most expensive, so I need to reduce the cost of that one first.

Comment: To compare speed I compiled your `get_r` and `get_r_profile` functions in plain C. The plain C `get_r_profile` appeared to be 2.5-3 faster than the Cython one so maybe it's an option to compile `get_r` separately and link to it from Cython? Interestingly, depending on the optimization flags the compiler seems to skip the call to `get_r` altogether! Dunno how this plays out with the C code generated by Cython but maybe something like this causes the difference in timing that you see.

Answer (score 5):

According to your comment, the line computing `r` is the most expensive. If that's the case, then I suspect it's the trig function calls that are killing performance.

By Pythagoras, `cos(x)**2 + sin(x)**2 == 1` so you can skip one of those calls by computing

```
cos_oa2 = cos(omega - A)**2
sin_oa2 = 1 - cos_oa2
r = 1. / sqrt(sqrt(l2) * cos_oa2 + sqrt(l1) * sin_oa2)
```

(Or maybe flip them: on my machine, `sin` seems faster than `cos`. Might be a NumPy glitch, though.)

Comment: Thanks, this improved the performance by about 10%. I also noticed just now that `return r` consumes about 50% of the computation time! If I replace `return r` by `return 0.5`, I get a massive speed up, so I suspect some C-to-Python overhead is involved.

Comment: @MPA: strange, that shouldn't happen in a `cdef` function with a declared return type, I think.

Comment: I've updated my original question with some additional information

Comment: @MPA: try assigning the result from each function to an appropriately-typed dummy variable. Cython might be converting the output to `PyObject*`.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Maybe if your function is not returning anything from the computations, some computations are being skipped by the compiler? (Just a suggestion)

Answer (score 2):

The output of

```
cython -a
```

shows that the division by 0 is tested. You might want to remove this check if you're 200% sure it won't happen.

To use the C division you can add the following directive to the top of your file :

```
# cython: cdivision=True
```

I'd link the official documentation but I can't access it right now. You have some information here (p15) : https://python.g-node.org/python-summerschool-2011/_media/materials/cython/cython-slides.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using that decorator didn't result in any performance gain. Besides, I am not certain a division by zero will never occur.

Comment: There are other tips in the PDF I linked, such as using a more aggressive optimization for the compiler. If the input values may be repeated among the million times the program runs, you can try caching the results in a dictionary. Another idea is to use tables for cos() and sin() but it depends on the numerical precision you need.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not related to Cython, but should mention some points which might be helpful.

1. Defining vars before really knowing if they're needed might be not ideal. Move "cdef double l1, l2, A, r, g2, gs" after the "if g == 0" statement.
2. I would ensure that from "omega = omega*M_PI/180" the M_PI/180 part is only calculated once. E.g. some Python code:

   ```
   import timeit
   from math import pi

   def calc1( omega ):
       return omega * pi / 180

   SCALEDPI = pi / 180
   def calc2( omega ):
       return omega * SCALEDPI

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       took = timeit.repeat( stmt = lambda:calc1( 5 ), number = 10000 )
       print "Min. time: %.4f Max. time: %.4f" % ( min( took ), max( took ) )
       took = timeit.repeat( stmt = lambda:calc2( 5 ), number = 10000 )
       print "Min. time: %.4f Max. time: %.4f" % ( min( took ), max( took ) )
   ```

   calc1: Min. time: 0.0033 Max. time: 0.0034

   calc2: Min. time: 0.0029 Max. time: 0.0029
3. Try to optimize the calculations themself. They look rather complicated and I have a feeling that they can be simplified.

Comment: The M_PI/180 part should be handled by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first two suggestions didn't result in any performance gain. As for the third one: I don't think these equations can be simplified any further :(

Comment: The `cdef`s don't actually perform computations, and they have to be at the start of the function.